# How to get data to template with FormMixin in a posts DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have the code below, and would like to know how to display the saved data from the form in the same view? I have the Detailview of the Post, and the form to Answer this Post in the same view, but how do I also display the data saved from this form?

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = AnswerForm
    template_name = 'main/postdetail.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'


    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('postdetail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AnswerForm(initial={'post': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.created_by = self.request.user
        instance.post = self.object
        instance.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My model

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, I agree with that. I copied some code from my ListView. I updated with my model now (If you wonder why I asked about contenttype previously it's because I also have a comment model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redirect after a successful post request, so you can't display the form data then.

It looks like the redirect is back to the post detail view. In the template, you can display related answers along with the post:

```
{{ posts }}
{% for answer in posts.answer_set.all %}
    {{ answer.created_by }}
    {{ answer.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

It's confusing to use `context_object_name = 'posts'`, since you are displaying the detail for a single `post`. I suggest you change the view to:

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = AnswerForm
    template_name = 'main/postdetail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'  # or just remove this line since the default will be 'post'
```

Then you would display related answers in the template with:

```
{{ post }}
{% for answer in post.answer_set.all %}
    {{ answer.created_by }}
    {{ answer.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested, and it works perfectly! Thanks again for your knowledge and time!